# how to iteratively present a inorder and postorder (binary tree)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

code in python:

```
class Binary_tree:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
(...)
    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}; {}; {}]".format(self.key, self.left, self.right)

    def inorder(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.inorder()

        print(self.key)

        if self.right:
            self.right.inorder()

    def postorder(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.postorder()
        if self.right:
            self.right.postorder()

        print(self.key)
```

The above code is written recursively. I need iteratively. 
I am asking for help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to change a recursively algorithm to an iterative one it's very common to use a stack. In this case we can use it to maintain the information about which node should be processed. In the case of an preorder traversal we know that we should go in the following way: (Root, Left, Right) so we need to push the right element first because it's the last one that we want to get the value and finally we need to push the left element that it's the next one that we're going to get the information from.

```
        2         stack = [2] -> pop(2), push(3) push(1)
       / \        stack = [3,1] -> pop(1), push(7), push(0)
      /   \       stack = [3,7,0] -> pop(0), push(), push() 
     /     \      stack = [3,7] -> pop(7), push(), push()
    1       3     stack = [3] -> pop(3), push(), push()
   / \            
  0   7
```

Translating the idea to code:

```py
def preorder(root):
    stack, ans = [root], []
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        if node:
            ans.append(node.key)
            stack.append(node.right)
            stack.append(node.left)
    return ans
```

We can use a similar approach to do the post order traversal, so instead of pushing right first, we can push left instead and reverse the result.

```
        2         stack = [2] -> pop(2), push(1) push(3)
       / \        stack = [1,3] -> pop(3), push(), push()
      /   \       stack = [1] -> pop(1), push(0), push(7) 
     /     \      stack = [0,7] -> pop(7), push(), push()
    1       3     stack = [0] -> pop(0), push(), push()
   / \            
  0   7
```

```py
def postorder(root):
    stack, ans = [root], []
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        if node:
            ans.append(node.key)
            stack.append(node.left)
            stack.append(node.right)
    return ans[::-1]
```